# MySQL IF...THEN followed by Query Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-functions

Is something like this valid in MySQL:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION LOGIN_VALIDATE(IN uName VARCHAR(32),IN uPass VARCHAR(32))
RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
    DECLARE row_count BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE stored_pass VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE valid_return BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT count(*) INTO row_count FROM Login WHERE userId='uName';
    IF row_count = 1 THEN 
        SELECT pWord INTO stored_pass FROM Login WHERE userId='uName';
    END IF;
    IF stored_pass = 'uPass' THEN 
        SET valid_return = 1;
    END IF;
    RETURN valid_return;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I suppose that `userId` should be a primary key of  `Login`? Why do you run the first query into row_count?

Comment: Yes userId is a primary key. I store it in row_count to compare it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
DECLARE valid_return BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;

SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  INTO valid_return
  FROM LOGIN l
 WHERE l.userid = @uName
   AND l.pword = @uPass
```

Always try to minimize the number of passes over a table to get your desired result.  SQL is SET based, not procedural - SQL will work better for you when it is approached correctly.

Comment: That seems to do the job and yes this one is more efficient, but I am just perplexed why isn't my logic working and more so because Mimer validator give no major syntax error while the MySQL prompt indicates error near BEGIN.

Comment: @check123: You don't use single quotes to reference variables in MySQL - MySQL requires they either be prefixed with the "@" or not within single (or double) quotes.

Comment: It did not work initially but after removing @ and using no quotes it worked. Thanks!